# Docker-compose with odoo

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm trying to figure out how to implement docker using docker-compose.yml with database filter imported from postgres but still showing all database.

[image]

Comment: Please, don't use images to show code. Paste code directly into the question.

Comment: dont worry it is a demo.